# Drupal changing the text in a user select list

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

I have a cck field which is a user lookup. By default it looks at the "name". In my site we set the name to be the same as the email address and store the first and last name in a content profile.

When using the cck field the email adress in the name field is being shown. I wish to pull the content from the content profile instead. How would I override the select list (I will need to do this for all cck filed user lookups on the site).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using the autocomplete function on a user reference field.

In userreference.module you will find the function [userreference_menu](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/function/userreference_menu/6), an implementation of [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6). There you see that a request to example.com/userreference/autocomplete (that's what the autocomeplete field does) calls the [userreference_autocomplete](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/function/userreference_autocomplete/6) function (a 'menu callback'). Now, what you need to do, is:

1. Create a custom module (see the documentation on drupal.org)
2. Create a new autocomplete menu callback (you can use the code from userreference_autocomplete and change it the way you want)
3. Change the menu item for userreference/autocomplete by implementing [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu_alter/6) so it will call the function you created in step 2
4. Enable your module